# Bash: How to print additional column matching IP Address to Name

Tags: shell-script, text-processing, awk, netstat

I'm using `netstat` to collect information about connected IP's. And I have the following format:

```
netstat -tn 2>/dev/null | awk '/:80 / {print $5}' | sed 's/.*::ffff://' | sed 's/:.*//' | sor t | uniq -c | sort -nr
      5 81.133.113.200
      4 80.229.142.126
      2 94.136.36.29
      2 92.19.231.69
      2 85.159.56.230
      2 83.70.246.152
      2 81.131.118.236
      2 185.106.92.42
      1 92.19.232.88
      1 86.47.113.169
      1 86.168.206.46
      1 79.77.175.210
      1 46.19.141.238
      1 206.221.184.2
      1 192.198.95.6
```

What I was trying to accomplish is to match an IP to a hostname.

So if i have `name=$(IPADDRESSNAME)` stored somewhere and name matches ip address 81.133.113.200

I would like it to print in a format like that:

```
  5 81.133.113.200 - IPADDRESSNAME
  4 80.229.142.126
  2 94.136.36.29
  2 92.19.231.69
```

I have been reading column to try and do this, But I am unsure how to combine both column with a match on the address.

I am running this from with a Bash script, So I would be storing the hostnames in there.

I was thinking something like:

```
string=$(netstat -tn 2>/dev/null | awk '/:80 / {print $5}' | sed 's/.*::ffff://' | sed 's/:.*//' | sort | uniq -c | sort -nr)
if [[ $string == "81.133.113.200" ]]
then
  echo "Its XXXXXXXX HOST";
fi
```

Something kind of like this, Although this does not work, The logic is what am after but in-line.

Comment: Sorry, I don't understand what you mean with "I have been reading column to try and do this, But I am unsure how to combine both column with a match on the address." Could you explain this? Where do you get the hostname from?

Comment: Here is a link to the script i am running.
I was thinking about storing the Hostname / IP Address at the top of the file, and when Matched, i could have it print a name next to the IP Address. 
Here is a link to the whole script: 
http://pastebin.com/7NQagYSW

In simple terms, I wanted 3 Colums, (I already have 2)
Count: IP Addresss: Hostname 

I dont know how to Add a Colum along side what its already printing out to keep it inline to say if IP Address 81.133.113.200 print Its XXXXXXXX HOST

Its only about 10 IP Address ill be doing it with. not all of them.

Comment: Maybe am still being unclear. 
if i store: 
`Host2=$(8.8.8.8)`
And the ip Address from Netstat command prints out 8.8.8.8 I could like to display a custom name next to it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Give this tested version a try:

```
netstat -tn 2>/dev/null | awk '/:80 / {print $5}' | sed 's/.*::ffff://' | sed 's/:.*//' | sor t | uniq -c | sort -nr |\
while read index ipaddress ; do \
  printf "%s " "${index}" ;\
  getent hosts "${ipaddress}" ;\
  if [ $? -eq 2 ]; then \
    printf "%s\n" "${ipaddress}" ;\
  fi ;\
done
```

It is using the standard **getent** to query the **hosts** database in order to retrieve the hostname given its ip address.

The test:

```
5 81.133.113.200  host81-133-113-200.in-addr.btopenworld.com
4 80.229.142.126  garnerhome.plus.com
2 94.136.36.29    mail.e-trackit.co.uk
2 92.19.231.69    host-92-19-231-69.static.as13285.net
2 85.159.56.230
2 83.70.246.152   83-70-246-152-dynamic.b-ras1.prp.dublin.eircom.net
2 81.131.118.236  host81-131-118-236.range81-131.btcentralplus.com
2 185.106.92.42
1 92.19.232.88    host-92-19-232-88.static.as13285.net
...
```

Comment: I Like it :) Thanks :) 
This is what i ended up doing to get the output i wanted 
`echo -e ${YELLOW}"Current Active Connections to the Server Port 80"
TEST=$(netstat -tn 2>/dev/null | awk '/:80 / {print $5}' | sed 's/.*::ffff://' | sed 's/:.*//' | sed '/85.159.56/s/$/ ---  EKM SYSTEMS/' | sort | uniq -c | sort -nr)
echo -e "$TEST" | sed 's/EKM SYSTEMS/\'$'\033[31m&\033[(B\033[33m/' `
I like how this does the lookup on the Host, Thanks very much, Going away now to do abit of mix and match to get the best output :) Aprechate this thanks

Comment: @DaveHamilton : right ; **getent** is using the **gethostbyname2** system call (libc). Please accept this solution as the *Answer*.

Answer (score 1):

I forget Sed can be used to Append a line and not just remove content. 
So i used Sed to locate the String and append a line after it. 
Rather simple when you think about it.

I think i was over complicating the situation with outputting in colums

Simple one liner as an example:

```
  netstat -tn 2>/dev/null | awk '/:80 / {print $5}' | sed 's/.*::ffff://' | sed 's/:.*//' | sed '/8.8.8.8/s/$/ Its Google/' | sort | uniq -c | sort -nr
```

Comment: You can use a single `sed` with multiple expressions using `-e` (or separate your expressions using `;`, but that would make it less readable). Ex : `netstat -tn 2>/dev/null | awk '/:80 / {print $5}' | sed -e 's/.*::ffff://' -e 's/:.*//' -e '/8.8.8.8/s/$/ Its Google/' | sort | uniq -c | sort -nr`

Answer (score 1):

You could process the output line by line and print as per your requirements. Assuming you want to map addresses to hostnames from /etc/hosts, you could do something like this:

```
get_connected_hosts() {
  netstat -tn 2>/dev/null | awk '/:80 / {print $5}' | sed 's/.*::ffff://' | sed 's/:.*//' | sort | uniq -c | sort -nr
}

get_connected_hosts | while read line; do
  set -- $line
  result=$(grep $2 /etc/hosts | head -1 | awk '{ print $2 }')
  # or a reverse DNS lookup, result=$(dig +short -x $2)
  echo "$1 $2 - $result"
done | column -t
```

Answer (score 1):

```
netstat -tn | awk '/:80 / {print $5}' | sed -e 's/:.*//' | 
    xargs -i sh -c 'echo {} $(getent hosts {})' | 
    awk '$1 == $2 {print $2, $3; next}; {print}' | 
    sort | uniq -c | sort -nr
```

(can be all on one-line, I've added line-feeds to avoid horizontal scroll bars and to make it more readable)

This uses `xargs -i` (with implicit `-L 1`) to do a `getent hosts` lookup **before** running the `sort | uniq -c`.  This is more complicated than it needs to be because `getent` produces no output if the lookup doesn't return anything, so we need to ensure the IP address is printed by `echo`-ing it before the `getent`.  The second `awk` makes sure that only one IP address is printed per line.

Other alternatives would be to use `nslookup`, `dig -x` or `host -i` to do the IP to hostname lookup, but all of those would require even more processing of the output.

the `sed` after `awk` on the first line isn't really needed, we could do the same thing using `awk`'s `gsub()` function to modify `$5` before printing it, but I think doing it this way is more readable and easier to understand.